# Two types of users account in Django

Tags: python, django

I've form in HTML:

```
<form action=""> 
     <select> 
         <option>Freelancer</option>
         <option>Employer</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
</form>
```

When user will send the form I want check what account type user has selected. If user selected a Freelancer account I want save him to Freelancer model. If he selected Employer to Employer model.

How to use this in `forms.py` when the 
 `class Meta` would has two models?

Comment: What have you tried so far within your view function?

Comment: I think it would be easier to have one model and have a choice field in the model - [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices)